# Sending and testing HTML form through JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm working with a PHP dev and was tasked with sending an html form with 4 checkboxes as a JSON string to the server. However, whenever I click the send form button, the page is reset and I can't check if the form is being sent properly. If I add alerts or console.log to the JS code, they don't execute. I added **** to the website URL because I'd rather stay anonymous.

The form is supposed to send the 3 strings and the 4 checkboxes through 2 different JSON links. Later I'll add validation, now I just wanted to understand why is it not executing the code. I imagine alert isn't working because the page refreshes at submit, but how can I test if it's working then?

Thank you.

**This is the JS script:**

```
    $("#form1").submit(function(e) {
        //LADO SERVIDOR (ARQUIVO PHP) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15661/receber-ajax-json-post-no-php-e-retornar-no-sucesso
        e.preventDefault();
        var identificador = $(nome      )[0].value;
        var descricao     = $(descricao )[0].value;
        var password      = $(password  )[0].value;
        $('.somename').each(function(e){
            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            list = list + $(this).attr('id')+",";
        }); 
        $.getJSON('******/get?code=3001&desc='+descricao+'&key='+password+'&format=json&charset=utf-8&lang=pt_br', function(data){});
        $.getJSON('********/get?code=3004&id='+identificador+'&sr='+list+'&format=json&charset=utf-8&lang=pt_br', function(data){});
        alert(list);
    });
```

**The HTML (using Bootstrap) part:**

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Identificador do  empreendimento</label>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Identificador para identificar a  empreendimento" id="nome">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Descrição do  empreendimento</label>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Descreva o objetivo do empreendimento" id="descricao">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Palavra-chave</label>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Palavra-chave para acessar a  empreendimento" id="password">
                            </div>

<!--                             <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Static Control</label>
                                <p class="form-control-static">email@example.com</p>
                            </div> -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Selecione as fontes de energia</label>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                  <input class="somename" type="checkbox" id="1" value="1" name="eolica"> Eolica
                                  <br>
                                  <input class="somename" type="checkbox" id="2" value="2" name="solar"> Solar
                                  <br>
                                  <input class="somename" type="checkbox" id="3" value="3" name="biomassa"> Biomassa
                                  <br>
                                  <input class="somename" type="checkbox" id="4" value="4" name="phc"> PHC
                                   <br>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <a href="prevotacao.html" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Create enterprise &raquo;</a> -->
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" id="reset">Clean form &raquo;</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like Vue.JS?

Comment: I don't get the question, are you trying to receive some JSON from the server or to send some JSON to the server ?

Comment: If you aren't seeing console logs or alerts then your event handler isn't probably being set. i.e. your code could be running before the form is created, or you could be using the wrong css selector

Comment: Alex, I'm trying to send the form to the server.

Comment: You are aware you are sending GET requests instead of POST request right? And you are sending user and password as part of the url's query.

Comment: Which button are you clicking to submit. The only button I see is the rest button.  Have you tried to add a button of type submit?

Comment: If I understook @PatrickEvans comment: do you have your script inside a $(document).ready() wrapper?

Comment: dama, I do have one. I just happened to delete it by accident when pasting it here.

Comment: Juan, I tried both inside one or without one.

Answer (score 0):

3 points:

**1.** Alert might fail because there is no `list` var defined in your given scope (unless `list` was defined globally or in the parent function)

**2.** The $.getJson() API is listed at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ as

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success ] );
```

Here, `url` is URL to send the request, 
`data` is the data to send (your form data,) and `success` is a callback function, run upon successful return from the server.

You first need to correct the parameters to follow the order `(url, data, success)` then flesh out the `success` function. e.g.

```
$.getJSON(url, data, function(data) { /* do something with your data */ });
```

**3.** Note that since `getJSON` is asynchronous. This means the function is called and code continues even though the response has not returned.this means the success functions will not necessarily run in the order you expect and will have different scopes then your original function.

Comment: What I need to do is to send the variables id, desc and password alongside the number of the checked checkboxes through the url to the JSON server. The PHP dev made sure to tell me it needed to go through the URL and other parts of the website do the same.

Comment: It looks like your version of the getJSON call is allowed so the alert() not being called suggests that this form submit function is failing somewhere along the way. Check:
1) Is your form submit being called? Place a console.log() at the top of the function and see if it's called.
2) Next, check that you're getting all the data you expect from the form. Place another console.log() after the .each() call and log out that info.
If all of that works, the getJSON call should be called. **But...** more below...

Comment: **Note** if you have an error on the JSON server you won't see it, the function(data) is only called on success. See the [examples](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) at the jQuery API page for how to add .fail() and .always() callbacks to catch issues after the getJSON() call.